# Why does 定 (dìng) disable the monsters' movement in the movie 捉妖记 (Monster Hunt)?

Tags: characters, meaning-in-context, movies

In the movie 捉妖记 (zhuōyāojì), called Monster Hunt in English ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Hunt), [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6170484/), [Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8D%89%E5%A6%96%E8%AE%B0/14077516), [iQIYI](http://www.iqiyi.com/v_19rrnr18nc.html)), the movie's character 霍小岚 (Huòxiǎolán) attaches the Chinese hanzi

## [定](http://dict.cn/%E5%AE%9A) (dìng)

to the head of monsters, and this largely disables their movement.  It's used humorously in various scenes.

> [image: Monster with 定 stuck on his forehead]

I'm wondering what is significant about the character 定 in particular.

**Question**: Why does 定 disable the monsters' movement in Monster Hunt?

Among the definitions at dict.cn for [定](http://dict.cn/%E5%AE%9A), we have "to set" and "to fix".  It's possible it's used as short for [固定](http://dict.cn/%E5%9B%BA%E5%AE%9A), which has "immobilization" among its definitions.  Although, I'm just guessing here, and I feel like there is more to it, possibly even something historical.

Comment: In 1985's Mr. Vampire (僵尸先生), a taoist priest attaches a large yellow strip with some inscriptions to the forehead of vampires/zombies to immobilize them. I couldn't find what's written on them, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know the magic "定身法"(the body-immobilization magic) from the very famous TV show 《西游记》, in which the protagonist "孙悟空" uses it to immobilize monsters. The magic spell he uses is a single character "**定**". It went viral since then. Kids would joke around about it.

Nowadays, almost every native speaker knows this magic, given that 《西游记》 is such a popular TV show as well as its book.

Answer (score 4):

定 simply means to set or fix (in place). Essentially a "STOP" sign. No wonder the monsters stop! Plus there's probably a connotation with the TV show.

https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%AE%9A

Answer (score 2):

Modern oral Mandarin still use 定 as "prevent something to move". You can use 固定 instead, they're interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

定=to fix. 定-something, means fix something, make something still. it comes from the old tale. there is also an idiom that is called "葵花点穴手".